# Javascript OR no working as expected

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I have a sputility script that hides/shows specific fields when a specific choice is made in the other field.  I need everything with "MYPLAN" to be hidden if it is not selected in the source field.

I am trying to use || as the or statement but it is not working.  When I dont put in the || the code works fine.

```
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"> 
  </script>
<script src="https:///SiteAssets/sputility.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
// Get a the choice field
var choiceField = SPUtility.GetSPField('Opportunity Type');

// create a function to show or hide a field based on the selected choice 
Field value
var ShowHideField = function() {
var selectedFieldValue = choiceField.GetValue();
// Hide the 'Other Title' field if the selected value is 'Other'
if(selectedFieldValue != 'MyPlan for Monitoring' || selectedFieldValue != 
'MyPlan for Imaging') {
SPUtility.GetSPField('PCAM / CRAM Name').Hide();
SPUtility.GetSPField('Exec IT Sponsor / Title').Hide();
SPUtility.GetSPField('Exec Care Delivery Sponsor / Title').Hide();
SPUtility.GetSPField('Contract End Year').Hide();
SPUtility.GetSPField('Current Year Estimated Value ($M)').Hide();
SPUtility.GetSPField('Swat TeamEngaged').Hide();
SPUtility.GetSPField('Installed Base Documention').Hide();
SPUtility.GetSPField('SR SA and SR Clinical Consultant Engaged').Hide();
SPUtility.GetSPField('ZVP Feedback').Hide();
 }
 else {
SPUtility.GetSPField('PCAM / CRAM Name').Show();
SPUtility.GetSPField('Exec IT Sponsor / Title').Show();
SPUtility.GetSPField('Exec Care Delivery Sponsor / Title').Show();
SPUtility.GetSPField('Contract End Year').Show();
SPUtility.GetSPField('Current Year Estimated Value ($M)').Show();
SPUtility.GetSPField('Swat TeamEngaged').Show();
SPUtility.GetSPField('Installed Base Documention').Show();
SPUtility.GetSPField('SR SA and SR Clinical Consultant Engaged').Show();
SPUtility.GetSPField('ZVP Feedback').Show();

 }
 };

 // Call ShowHideField in Edit and Display form
ShowHideField();
 // attach the function to choice field
 $( choiceField.Dropdown).on('change', ShowHideField);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your test expression, as written, means

> if `selectedFieldValue` is not equal to "MyPlan for Monitoring" or it's not equal to "MyPlan for Imaging" then do the following ...

Think about it. If it *is* equal to `"MyPlan for Monitoring"`, then it's *not* equal to `"MyPlan for Imaging"`.  On the other hand, if it's equal to `"MyPlan for Imaging"`, then it's not equal to `"MyPlan for Monitoring"`. And clearly if it's not equal to either then the test will also be true.

No matter what, one side or the other of the `||` expression will be `true`.

What you want here is `&&` ("AND"), not `||`.